# Citations appearing as [?] when compiling document

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am new to LaTex and following a tutorial to create a bibliography. I have created a .tex file which shows one citation and I have also created a .bib file. In both cases, the citation key is the same. I compile my LaTex file and the .pdf shows '[?]' instead of my citation. I am also missing a .blg file.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

I am using Texworks (version 0.62, 2007-2017, 64-bit) downloaded from MikeTex (version 2.9).

From reading other posts, I have tried the following but with no success:
- Adding and removing .bib in `\bibliography{reftest}`
- Creating a new folder and starting from the beginning. 
- Followed instructions from: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number?rq=1)

[image: Tex file]
[image: Bib file]
[image: PDF output]

Any advice you can give would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: you need to run pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex

Comment: Welcome! Please do not paste code as images, but only as a code block. Every question should include a minimal working example (MWE) that can be copied and compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems.

Firstly, the `\bibliography` command should appear in the body of your document at the point you want the reference list to be printed.  In other words it needs to be place between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, *not* in the preamble before `\begin{document}`.

Secondly, the citation key needs to match the key of the entry in the bibliography file, *including the case*.  In your bibliography file the key is `Birdetal2001`, so you need to call `\cite{Birdetal2001}`, not `\cite{birdetal2001}`.

With these two changes you should get a correctly compiling document.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

Test 1 test 2 test 3 \cite{Birdetal2001}.

\bibliography{reftest}

\end{document}
```

and `reftest.bib`:

```
@Article{
Birdetal2001,
author = {Bird},
title = {Hunting},
journal = {Ecology},
volume = 50,
pages = {9-19},
year = {2001} }
```

Note that it is sufficient to write

```
\bibliography{reftest}
```

instead of `\bibliography{reftest.bib}`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! This solved my problem and my references are working perfectly now. The inclusion of the correct code was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

How to run LaTeX file to print Bibliography?

Step 1: Run `pdflatex filename.tex`

Step 2: Run `bibtex filename.aux`

Step 3: Run again `pdflatex filename.tex`